# use of "304 Not Modified" header from php

Tags: php, http, http-headers, cache-control

I have a question about "304 Not Modified" header from PHP.
Exactly: i have a page with multiple arguments which determine the output. The problem is that `header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');` delivers same output no matter the arguments.
How can I deliver different info using arguments and using the headers.

ps: i need th`header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');` because my output is preety big however it is not changing, also it will save bandwidth.

Comment: So what's the problem with checking the argument and deciding which headers/output to send?

Comment: the problem is that i receive same output for domain.com/page/1 as for domain.com/page/2

Comment: Well send different output from you server-side script then.

Comment: can you give an example?